# matplotlib not showing result

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I run this little program ( a little experiment to see a linear transformation of a chosen vector), the python launcher icon on my mac starts to activate itself by bouncing on the dock but then nothing is displayed. What is the problem?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def linear_transformation(up_sx,up_dx,down_sx,down_dx):
    x_vect_val=(input('what is the X value of the vector?'))
    y_vect_val=(input('what is the Y value of the vector?'))
    x_vect_transfval=str((int(x_vect_val)*str(up_sx))+(int(y_vect_val)*str(up_dx)))
    y_vect_transfval=str((int(x_vect_val)*str(down_sx))+(int(y_vect_val)*str(down_dx)))
    xvals=[x_vect_val,x_vect_transfval]
    yvals=[y_vect_val,y_vect_transfval]
    plt.plot(xvals,yvals)
    plt.show
```

It might be some stupid reason that I don't know, I am a beginner

linear_transformation(1,2,0,1)

[the icon activating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og6VB.png)

Comment: You did not call the last function : `plt.show()`.

Comment: Problem solved I guess .....